# how to use redux thunks with redux toolkit in custom useFetch for fetching api data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

im new to the redux toolkit here is my problem
im fetching data every time by creating own custom useFetch file for handling loading , success, error status
i used the same way with redux toolkit by creating createSlice method for accesing reducers and actions

this is working successfully and getting data from this way by dispaching actions and reducers
but i did't used the **createAsyncThunk** from redux toolkit

my confusion is **is this currect way to fetch data from custom useFetch or should i use createAsyncthunk**

Im not sure how to use createAsyncThunk in custom useFetch

if anyone knows the answer that is so appreciatable

posted my all files below

**if i get answer with createAsyncThunk in custom useFetch that is soo appreciable**

thanks advance

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import useFetchData from "./Components/useFetchData";
import { actions } from "./Slices/CounterSlice";
const App = () => {
  useFetchData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
  const apiData = useSelector((s) => s);

  console.log(apiData.api);
  return (
    <>
      {apiData.api.status !== "success" && <h1>hello</h1>}
      {apiData.api.status === "success" &&
        apiData.api.apiData.map((el) => {
          return <h6 key={el.id}>{el.title}</h6>;
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

custom **useFetchData.js** file

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { ApiActions } from "../Slices/ApiSlice";
const useFetchData = (link) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(ApiActions.loadingTime());
      const getData = await fetch(link);
      const toJson = await getData.json();
      dispatch(ApiActions.successTime(toJson));
    } catch {
      dispatch(ApiActions.errorTime());
    }
  }, [link]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);
};

export default useFetchData;
```

this is **createSlice** file for creating actions and reducers

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const apiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "api",
  initialState: {
    status: "idle",
    apiData: [],
    error: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    loadingTime: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "Loading";
    },
    successTime: (state, action) => {
      state.apiData = action.payload;
      state.status = "success";
    },
    errorTime: (state, action) => {
      state.apiData = [];
      state.status = "error";
    },
  },
});
export const ApiActions = apiSlice.actions;
export const apiReducers = apiSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one way or the other. Example with createAsyncThunk:

```
export const checkIfAuthenticated = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/checkIsAuth",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8080/dj-rest-auth/token/verify/",
      { token: localStorage.getItem("access") }
    );
    thunkAPI.dispatch(getUserInfo());
    return response.data;
  }
);
```

Then you handle loading, success, error status as before:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(checkIfAuthenticated.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
      })
      .addCase(checkIfAuthenticated.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        snackbar({ error: "Nie jesteś zalogowany" });
      })
  },
```

However, if you have a lot of API queries, the optimal solution is to use [redux toolkit query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) or [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/). These two libraries make queries a lot better.
If you care about code cleanliness and ease, check them out.